# Creating a functioning dialog box in Balsamiq

Tags: mockups, mockup-tool, balsamiq

I want to demonstrate a working dialog box in [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/). I can mock one up but I want it to open and close when I click on a page element.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3):

The feature you need to achive your goal is called [linking](http://support.balsamiq.com/customer/portal/articles/111742). With it you can connect several static mockups. The result will be a click through prototype.

What you need are following views:

1. A view when the dialog is closed
2. A view when the dialog is open
3. The dialog with text (optional)
4. A view when the dialog is closed. It could be the first or if you want to show the progress you could modify the initial view to have text.

Once you have the 4 mockups you can specify the links.